# Should I open source my android application?

Tags: android, open-source

I took some methods (not all) from free open source desktop application under GPL. This application written in C++ language, I convert those methods from C++ into Java code and used them in my android application.

**So, Should I open source my android application?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agreed with what has been answered so far... you have to...

Now, if for some reason, you would prefer to not release the source code, include the copyright notice and be obligated under GPL, you would need to rewrite those functions from scratch as a "clean room implementation" (implement only from the specifications / description, without taking any "inspiration" from the original work). If you can do that and somehow prove in case there is a dispute that you did actually do it, then you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could I open source only taken functions or I have open source all my application source code?

Comment: The code for the whole product that includes some code under GPL

Answer (score 3):

It's not a matter of *should* you -- you're legally obligated to open source it if you distribute it at all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I understand from you I have to open source my all work not only token methods?

Comment: GPL doesn't state that you can just open source a portion of your binary, it says you must provide everything necessary (including makefiles / project files, etc.) required to allow someone else to rebuild (along with any changes they wish to make).